# CSS bootstrap: why does my page view differently in mobile browsers Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Here is my code that will render an input field on screen:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 ....
<div class="form-group ">
       <label class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-2 control-label" id="categoryLabel">Request *</label>
       <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
             <select id="category" name="" class="form-control">
               //options
             </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

This looks perfect in a PC browser but after a client's feedback, i noticed that Firefox on android doesnt render it properly:
[image: firefox on left, chrome on right]

the class form-control has the following css:

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out     .15s;
  transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

The rest of the classes are all bootstrap v3.0.0 classes.

Any ideas on how i can make the firefox browser render like the chrome browser?

Thanks

Comment: Share your HTML because it's there where is the problem.

Comment: I did at the top of my question

Comment: Yes sorry. What viewport you have configured?

Comment: It seems your widths are not proper. `<label class="col-xs-8` should ideally be `<label class="col-xs-12`?

Comment: ill add the viewport into my question. Its  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @Abhitalks has a good reason, but it doesn't explain differents behaviours in chrome and firefox in same device. You miss the `<div class="row">` too, it's important that structure to be `row > col + col ; row > col + col ` and nothing else in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing grid for label.

`<label class="col-xs-8` - change to `<label class="col-xs-12`

Comment: @afelixj Please explain the reason behind this. Also, why it works on one browser and not on the other?

Comment: I havent marked it as an answer for that reason. I am grateful that he offered a solution however and thus upvoted